# error in trivy Vulnerability scanning: filesystem scan error & misconfiguration scan error

Tags: security, gitlab-ci, trivy, devsecops

I am using Trivy to scan for Vulnerability scanning in the GitLab CI CD pipeline.

When I use `$ trivy fs --exit-code 0 --severity UNKNOWN,LOW,MEDIUM,HIGH,CRITICAL --scanners vuln,config ./. --timeout $TRIVY_TIMEOUT`

I am getting the error :

```
    FATAL   filesystem scan error: scan error: scan failed: failed analysis: failed to call hooks: post handler error: misconfiguration scan error: scan config error: 4 errors occurred:
policies/cloud/policies/aws/rds/disable_cluster_skip_final_snapshot.rego:26: rego_type_error: undefined ref: cluster.skipfinalsnapshot.value
    cluster.skipfinalsnapshot.value
            ^
            have: "skipfinalsnapshot"
            want (one of): ["backupretentionperioddays" "encryption" "engine" "instances" "performanceinsights" "publicaccess" "replicationsourcearn"]
```

So could someone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems to be an bug from trivy so have reported it here https://github.com/aquasecurity/defsec/issues/1466

Comment: 404 response - there are no issues in https://github.com/aquasecurity/defsec/ project